# Issue on Selecting Element in Browser Current Page by Chrome Custom Add-on

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have a chrome custom Add-on which has a button like

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">  
 <button  class="btn" id="loader"> Find</button>
</div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="custom.js"></script>
</body>
```

and in custom.js I have

```
 $(function(){
   $( "#loader" ).on( "click", function( e ) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#res a").each(function(){
        console.log("You Got It!");
      });
   });
 });
```

what I would like to do is finding all `<a>` in the `#res` div in a page but it looks like the query only is searching the add-on body! can you please let me know how to do this?

> Update: Manifest JSON

```
{
    "name": "Data",
    "version": "0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
     "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "Get Data"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the manifest.json? Might have some clues.

Comment: Thanks @MattiPrice I just updated the post with `Manifest` JSON

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by previous answer, first of all you need to have access to the page's tab to do that. (I believe `"permissions": ["activeTab"]` will do the job for you.)

Secondly, your JS code is running on the popup window not on the current tab window. 
So the behaviour you are experiencing is expected. Your document is the popup's document. It's where your jquery is loaded, your click handler is registered and your dom query runs. What I understand you want, is to run some query in the active tab's document, when an event in the popup happens.

I believe in your case you need to use programmatic JS injection (read [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi) about this.)
To explain myself, I think you want to inject some JS code in the active tab's window when an event on your popup window is triggered. You could do that with `chrome.tabs.executeScript` pretty easily. (See the full documentation of the method [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript)).

For example try changing your code for a moment to

```
$(function(){
    $( "#loader" ).on( "click", function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        chrome.tabs.executeScript({
            code: 'console.log(document.getElementById("res"))'
        });
    });
});
```

and see what happens. I hope that helps a bit!

Comment: Thanks Faiakism I tried your solution but I am getting this error `Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot access a chrome:// URL` on popup console

Comment: Did you try to click the button while you were on `chrome://extensions/` tab or something?

Comment: By default you cannot access a chrome:// url page. Try it when the page you want to query is on the active tab and see the tab's console too.

Answer (score -1):

Since your extension doesn't have any permissions, this is likely the issue. Try setting it to

```
{
"name": "Data",
"version": "0.1",
"manifest_version": 2,
 "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Get Data"
},
"permissions": [
    "activeTab"]
}
```

Comment: thanks Matti I update the manifest but still looks like I am not accessing  the elements of current page?

Comment: I just test this again with adding `$('body').css('background','red');` and it just changed the background color of the popup element for add-on not the current page

Comment: So what is the expected behavior that isn't occurring currently?